# Request a Page Access Token in C# SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

As a proof of concept for a simple background application, I used the Graph API Explorer to create an access token for my app to post something to the wall of a page I maintain.  It worked fine.  Naturally, however, the token expires.

So now I'm trying to have the background application automatically request a new page access token each time it runs.  And I'm having a lot of trouble finding a concrete definition of how to do that.  There's no shortage of information regarding Facebook and Access Tokens, but nothing seems to demonstrate how to have a background application post to a page.  (Not post to a user's wall, not display a login dialog to a user since it's a background application, etc.)

I can fetch an access token in code easily enough by reading the response from a web request to this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={MY_APP_ID}&client_secret={MY_APP_SECRET}
```

Of course, that "access token" doesn't work when trying to post to the page's wall.  It says that the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.  The action I'm performing is pretty simple:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(GetFacebookAccessToken());
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "this is a test";
dynamic result = client.Post("{MY_PAGE_ID}/feed", parameters);
```

I've read in some places that I'll need to make a second request, using the first access token, to get the page access token.  But I can't seem to find examples of how to do that.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

- I have a Facebook page.
- I have a Facebook app which serves no other purpose than to provide a means for a local background application to access said page.
- I just need that application to be able to authenticate so it can post something to the page.
- (And if there's a step I need to perform in the Facebook UI to permanently give the application permission to do this, I think I've performed that step but it would be good to double check somehow.)

**Edit:**  It's been described to me that I need to obtain a long-lived user access token and, using that, obtain a page access token.  The theory is that said page access token won't expire.  However, what's not clear to me is how one accomplishes this.

I've read [the page describing the deprecation of `offline_access`](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), as well as [the page describing server-side access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/).  However, I'm clearly misunderstanding something.  In the former, it references the latter for obtaining the proper token.  The latter, however, includes steps for presenting a login to the user, having them accept permissions, and using the response from that login.

Being a background process that runs unattended, presenting any sort of question to a user (which would be me) isn't really an option.  I've also been told that I can't do a one-time request from my browser to get an access token because that is, by definition, client-side interaction and not part of the necessary server-side flow.  (It seems odd to me that the service would care if a RESTful request comes from a web browser vs. from an application, but I'm not familiar enough with OAuth or the Facebook API to really make that call.)

So, if I can perform some manual steps to get a permanent access token for the app to post to the Facebook page, what are those steps?  Conversely, if I can perform some automated steps in the application to acquire access each time it runs, what are those steps?

(Making a few more API calls from the application adds a second or two of running time to an otherwise once-a-day process, so it makes no difference to me which approach to take.)

Comment: You can not get new tokens without user interactions. If you get a page access token using a _long-lived_ user access token however, the page token will not expire by default.

Comment: User tokens expire after 60 days, but page access tokens do not. And how to get them, I just said.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: The first piece of code you showed is for getting an app access token. For a user token, you have to follow the server-side flow as outlined in the docs.

Comment: First sentence of my first comment. You’ll have to do it _once_ to get a long-lived user access token.

Comment: And how exactly did you do that once …?

Comment: And what would you call this, you sitting in front of a browser, interacting with a website – if _not_ “user interaction”? And yes, of course this token expired quickly, because it was acquired client-side …

Comment: Back to my original answer: If you get a page access token using a long-lived user access token however, the page token will not expire by default.

Comment: And I don’t know how to answer more clearly – you either get a long-lived user access token by using the server-side flow in the first place, or by extending a short-lived one _as described in the link I posted._ And as for getting a page access token, that’s described in the login section of the docs in the developer section as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first I just went into the Facebook Application settings and re-enabled the deprecated "offline access" permission.  Said application settings can be found at a URL like this:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APPLICATION_ID}/advanced
```

However, since everything keeps referring to that setting as being "deprecated" then I didn't want to use that as a long-term solution.  It may get removed entirely, it may be unsafe in certain circumstances, etc.  Better to use recommended functionality.

So here's what I was able to piece together from a scavenger hunt through updated documentation, outdated documentation, a sea of outdated internet posts, and PHP code which mostly made assumptions about functionality that aren't true in all cases...

Visit the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and select your Facebook Application from the drop-down menu.  Click "Get Access Token" and select the permissions you want.  (For mine I went to the "Extended Permissions" tab and selected "Managed Pages" and "Publish Stream.")  You will be prompted (in my browser it was in a new tab) with a familiar screen where the Facebook Application is asking you, the user, to grant it the permissions you just selected.  (You've seen this before if you've ever agreed to use a Facebook Application before.)

The value it produces in the Graph API Explorer (a long string of random-ish characters) is your "Short Lived User Access Token."

As described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal) in "Scenario 4: Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint" access this URL in your web browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
  client_id={APPLICATION_ID}
  &client_secret={APPLICATION_SECRET}
  &grant_type=fb_exchange_token
  &fb_exchange_token={SHORT_LIVED_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

(You can obtain the `{APPLICATION_SECRET}` value on the basic settings page for your Facebook Application: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APPLICATION_ID}/summary`)

This will return another Access Token as such:

```
access_token={LONG_LIVED_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}&expires=5184000
```

This `access_token` value (another long string of random-ish characters) is your "Long Lived User Access Token."  The `expires` value is in seconds, which translates into 60 days.

Now we hop over to the [Page API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page) and take a look at the section on [Page Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens).  This, along with the basic structure of Graph API requests exemplified [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (scroll down to the part where it shows a bulleted list of sample links which include `access_token` specifiers, which you'll need to specify here because you're requesting non-public information) leads you to request this in your browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{FACEBOOK_USER_ID}/accounts?
  access_token={LONG_LIVED_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

This will return a JavaScript object containing lots of useful information about the Facebook Pages and Facebook Applications your user account controls.  In my case the Page and the Application had the same name, but it's easy to tell them apart from the `category` values or, if all else fails, the `id` values.  Find the Page that the background application running on your machine will need to access and copy its `access_token` (the third and final long string of random-ish characters).  The whole node looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Some Facebook Application Name",
  "access_token": "{LONG_LIVED_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
  "category": "Musician/band",
  "id": "{APPLICATION_ID}",
  "perms": [
    "ADMINISTER",
    "EDIT_PROFILE",
    "CREATE_CONTENT",
    "MODERATE_CONTENT",
    "CREATE_ADS",
    "BASIC_ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

This is your "Long Lived Page Access Token." This is the value you use to initialize the FacebookClient object in the code.  Then, posting a simple status update is as easy as:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("{LONG_LIVED_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "This is a my status update.";
dynamic result = client.Post("{FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID}/feed", parameters);
```

Supposedly this "Long Lived Page Access Token" does *not* expire after 60 days like the "Long Lived User Access Token" does.  I'll find out in 59 days, I guess.

---

NB: The curly braces in my examples are part of the placeholder for actual values.  Do not use the curly braces in the actual requests.  So something like this:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APPLICATION_ID}/advanced
```

becomes something like this, for example:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/123456/advanced
```

where `123456` is the actual Facebook Application ID.

Comment: did you ever get this working to satisfaction?  I am trying to figure out a way to give an MVC site permanent read access to a specific FB user account.  This, so that I can effectively 'mirror' the FB photo albums in the MVC website's gallery page.  Sound like the same hurdle you are having here...I don't want the user to log in, I want the page to just be able to read from FB

Comment: is it possible to get the {SHORT_LIVED_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN} programmatically? exactly no login page.. the only user allowed to post to page wall will be the admin so I how do I get it programmatically?

Comment: What is the FACEBOOK_USER_ID ? I tried putting in my personal numeric ID but got back an empty data array.

Answer (score -1):

> Being a background process that runs unattended, presenting any sort of question to a user (which would be me) isn't really an option.

As I already said, you only have to do it **once**.

You get your non-expiring page access token, copy&paste that into your app – and from then on your app can do server-side whatever it wants to do happily everafter.

> I've also been told that I can't do a one-time request from my browser to get an access token because that is, by definition, client-side interaction and not part of the necessary server-side flow.

The server-side auth flow for getting a user access token also needs to take part partly in the browser.

It does not matter, if you get a short-lived token via the client-side auth flow and extend it afterwards, or if you get a long-lived one using the server-side auth flow.

> (It seems odd to me that the service would care if a RESTful request comes from a web browser vs. from an application […])

Facebook does not want users to give their login credentials to any third party. Therefor, the process of getting a *user* access token always has to take part in the browser, with the user login in to Facebook.

> So, if I can perform some manual steps to get a permanent access token for the app to post to the Facebook page, what are those steps?

Get a long-lived user access token with manage_pages permission. (Or get a short-lived one, and extend it). And then, use that long-lived token to request a page access token for the target page, in the way that is described in the docs.